# How to fill column names in a multiindexed pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

My dataframe columns look like this:

```
>> df.columns

output:

MultiIndex([(                    'Month',                      nan),
        (                           'TG',                      nan),
        (                        'Reach',                  'level'),
        (                            nan,                   'plan'),
        (                            nan,             'sth (p.p.)'),
        (                            nan,                  'final'),
        (                   'Prime Time',                  'final'),
        (                            nan,                    'AGB'),
        (                            nan,            'diff (p.p.)'),
        (                   'Prime Time',             'diff p.p.')],
       names=[None, 'Campaign'])
```

I want to ffill names like this:

```
MultiIndex([(                    'Month',                      nan),
        (                           'TG',                      nan),
        (                        'Reach',                  'level'),
        (                        'Reach',                   'plan'),
        (                        'Reach',             'sth (p.p.)'),
        (                        'Reach',                  'final'),
        (                   'Prime Time',                  'final'),
        (                   'Prime Time',                    'AGB'),
        (                   'Prime Time',            'diff (p.p.)'),
        (                   'Prime Time',             'diff p.p.')],
       names=[None, 'Campaign'])
```

Finally I would like to get a flatten dataframe with one names row:

```
'Month',
'TG',
'Reach level',
'Reach plan',
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) for DataFrame and [`DataFrame.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrame.ffill.html) for forward fill missing values, last convert back to `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html) with pass `df.columns.names`:

```
nan = np.nan
L = [('Month', nan), ('TG', nan), 
     ('Reach', 'level'), 
     (nan, 'plan'),
     (nan, 'sth (p.p.)'),
     (nan, 'final'), 
     ('Prime Time', 'final'), 
     (nan, 'AGB'), 
     (nan, 'diff (p.p.)'),
     ('Prime Time', 'diff p.p.')]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L, names=[None, 'Campaign']))
```

---

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.to_frame().ffill(), 
                                      names=df.columns.names)
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([(     'Month',           nan),
            (        'TG',           nan),
            (     'Reach',       'level'),
            (     'Reach',        'plan'),
            (     'Reach',  'sth (p.p.)'),
            (     'Reach',       'final'),
            ('Prime Time',       'final'),
            ('Prime Time',         'AGB'),
            ('Prime Time', 'diff (p.p.)'),
            ('Prime Time',   'diff p.p.')],
           names=[None, 'Campaign'])
```

How it working:

```
print (df.columns.to_frame())
                                 0     Campaign
           Campaign                            
Month      NaN               Month          NaN
TG         NaN                  TG          NaN
Reach      level             Reach        level
NaN        plan                NaN         plan
           sth (p.p.)          NaN   sth (p.p.)
           final               NaN        final
Prime Time final        Prime Time        final
NaN        AGB                 NaN          AGB
           diff (p.p.)         NaN  diff (p.p.)
Prime Time diff p.p.    Prime Time    diff p.p.
```

---

```
print (df.columns.to_frame().ffill())
                                 0     Campaign
           Campaign                            
Month      NaN               Month          NaN
TG         NaN                  TG          NaN
Reach      level             Reach        level
NaN        plan              Reach         plan
           sth (p.p.)        Reach   sth (p.p.)
           final             Reach        final
Prime Time final        Prime Time        final
NaN        AGB          Prime Time          AGB
           diff (p.p.)  Prime Time  diff (p.p.)
Prime Time diff p.p.    Prime Time    diff p.p.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) to be able to access the `ffill` method, then convert back to MultiIndex with [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.columns.to_frame().ffill(),
                                      names=df.columns.names)
```

Example output:

```
         Month  TG Reach                       Prime Time                          
Campaign   NaN NaN level plan sth (p.p.) final      final AGB diff (p.p.) diff p.p.
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the code is just to recreate your example. The main point is `.to_series()` which allows me to use `ffil()` on the index type.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ["first",np.nan, 1],
        [np.nan,"abc",2],
        ["last","efg",3],
    ],
    columns=["idx1", "idx2", "val"]
)

# set multiindex
df = df.set_index(["idx1", "idx2"])

# at this point df looks like your example

level0_filled = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series().ffill()
level1_raw = df.index.get_level_values(1)

df = df.set_index([level0_filled, level1_raw])
```

Output as expected (note, it looks like the second value in first column is missing, but this is just the multiindex providing a more cleaner view in case of duplicate indices)

[image]